# WiX Toolset Light.exe -v verbose does not produce any additional output

Tags: logging, wix, light, verbose

I am trying to investigate an issue when building my WiX.3.11.2 based MSIs and so have added the -v command light option but am not seeing any change in the output and indeed the build logs are the same size before and after the change. Below is an example output:-

```
2023-10-16T15:29:31.4812386Z   e:\3201\s\WiX\Installers\msi\packages\WiX.3.11.2\build\..\tools\Light.exe -out e:\3201\s\Binaries\x86\Release\XFS3Simulators.msi -pdbout e:\3201\s\Binaries\x86\Release\XFS3Simulators.wixpdb -v -cultures:null -contentsfile obj\Release\XFS3Simulators.wixproj.BindContentsFileListnull.txt -outputsfile obj\Release\XFS3Simulators.wixproj.BindOutputsFileListnull.txt -builtoutputsfile obj\Release\XFS3Simulators.wixproj.BindBuiltOutputsFileListnull.txt -wixprojectfile e:\3201\s\WiX\Installers\msi\XFS3Simulators\XFS3Simulators.wixproj -v obj\Release\Product.wixobj e:\3201\s\Binaries\x86\Release\XFS3SimulatorsBinary.wixlib
2023-10-16T15:29:37.7312537Z ##[error]light.exe(0,0): Error LGHT0001: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)
2023-10-16T15:29:37.7312537Z light.exe : error LGHT0001: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) [e:\3201\s\WiX\Installers\msi\XFS3Simulators\XFS3Simulators.wixproj]
2023-10-16T15:29:37.9031320Z Done Building Project "e:\3201\s\WiX\Installers\msi\XFS3Simulators\XFS3Simulators.wixproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

I do note that I have set the '-v' option twice in the above example but I get the same level of out put when a single -v has been set.

Any suggestions as to how to get verbose logging enabled?

Comment: My question has been marked down but as no comment added I am not sure what more I need to add. I have searched for similar issues but without luck, have confirmed the relevant parameter '-v' is being used and checked that it fails to have any effect both on our autobuild servers and locally. Locally its built from within Visual Studio. Normally if you provide an incorrect command line i.e. -v was not recognised it would output the help info which it does not do so -v must be correct. So either I already have verbose logging enabled or its output else where but I see no info on that in help